# Automatic formatting in WPF TextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox

I try to create a simple Hex Input Control. In this control there should be a space char be added after 2 chars while the user is editing. The user should not be forced to press the space bar, the space should be added automatically.
The space chars should then not be in the binded value. There also should not be a fixed length for the hex string (like it would be with a masked textbox).

Is there an extension or control available for this or has anybody already created such a control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution would be doing this with a converter:

```
public class SpaceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string newValue = "";
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (char c in value.ToString())
        {
            if (cnt == 2)
            {
                 newValue += " ";
                 cnt=0;
            }
            newValue += c;
            cnt++;
        }
        return newValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Tostring().Replace(" ","");
    }
}
```

EDIT: To set the cursor I created a attached property which takes care about the formatting:

```
public class TextBoxFormatter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableFormattingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnableFormatting", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxFormatter),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox tb = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            bool value = (bool)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
            tb.TextChanged -= TBTextChanged;
            if (value)
            {
                Format(tb, true);
                tb.TextChanged += TBTextChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SetEnableFormatting(TextBox element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(EnableFormattingProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetEnableFormatting(TextBox element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(EnableFormattingProperty);
    }

    private static void TBTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Format(sender as TextBox);
    }

    private static void Format(TextBox tb, bool init = false)
    {
        if (tb != null)
        {
            int ci = tb.CaretIndex;
            string newValue = "";
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (char c in tb.Text)
            {
                if (c != ' ')
                {
                    if (cnt > 0 && ShouldFormat(cnt))
                    {
                        newValue += " ";
                        if (ci > cnt && init)
                            ci++;
                    }
                    cnt++;
                    newValue += c;
                }
            }
            tb.Text = newValue;
            SetCaret(tb, ci);
        }
    }

    private static void SetCaret(TextBox tb, int oldCaret)
    {
        if (oldCaret <= 0 || oldCaret >= tb.Text.Length)
            return;

        if (tb.Text[oldCaret-1] != ' ' && tb.Text[oldCaret] != ' ')
            tb.CaretIndex += oldCaret;
        else
            tb.CaretIndex = oldCaret+1;
    }

    private static bool ShouldFormat(int index)
    {
        return index%2 == 0;
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
<TextBox ns:TextBoxFormatter.EnableFormatting="True"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't fulfills the criteria '.. while the user is editing." The Converter is only called when the user leaves the textbox.

Comment: @RolandBär No, if you set the property UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your binding it updates the value immediately when the user types.

Comment: Yes, this works but another problem occures: When typing the third character, the space is inserted but the cursor remains at the position. So typing 1-2-3-4 results in "12 43", occuring for every inserted space again... Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Not perfect (some small defects when deleting) but the best answer, so I mark it a answered. Should be good enough for my purpose...

Comment: How about you make it perfect. ;) Keep in mind that StackOverflow isn't thought to provide you perfect code that you can copy and paste, but give you an example/idea how to solve the issue BY YOURSELF.

Comment: My comment was not thougth as an offense but for documentation purposes, so other people will see that it works but has some issues. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own control that does this, by overriding it's `OnTextChanged` method

```
public class HexTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool isUserTextChaned = true;

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isUserTextChaned)
        {
            isUserTextChaned = false;

            string temp = Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            // Support for backspace
            if (e.Changes.First().RemovedLength > 0 && !Text.EndsWith(" "))
            {
                temp = temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - e.Changes.First().RemovedLength);
            }

            // Insert spaces
            temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"(.{2})", "$1 ");

            // Update text
            Text = temp;

            isUserTextChaned = true;

            // Set cursor
            Select(Text.Length, Text.Length);

            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Explaination:

Since every change to the `Text` property will fire the `TextChanged` event, to avoid recursion I've added the `isUserTextChanged` field to determine that the `TextChanged` was fired externally.

Next, every third character we redefine the `Text` property with a ' ' inbetween every two chars.

Finally, we set the cursor to the end of the `Text` by selecting the last char `Select(Text.Length, Text.Length);`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you help me how to manipulate the text to get a usable control? Just adding a space (`Text += " ";`) moves the cursor to the start of the string, so typing 1-2-3-4 results in "4312___" (where _ means space).

Comment: This resolves the Problem of the spaces appearing at the end but not the problem that the cursor moves to the start of the TextBox, so the result of typing 1-2-3-4 is "_34_12", but it should be "12_34_".

Comment: @RolandBär To set the cursor to the end use `Select(Text.Length, Text.Length);` Regardless, I've updated my answer but if your code works with the `Select` method, use it since it is much simplier :) good luck

Comment: @RolandBär Updated my answer with a much simpler implementation using regex, and added support for backspace

Comment: Your solution puts the cursor at the end of the text, even while editing in the middle of the string. So I'll go with the accepted answer.